# Weird MergeFields

Tags: c#, xml, openxml

I've encountered a weird behavior when adding `MergeFields` in docx document.
I created .docx with `MergeFields` manually, and then tried to fulfill them with data.
Some fields were processed right, but some - remains unprocessed.
    After investigation, I've figured out that "good" fields looks in docx/word/document.xml like

```
<w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> MERGEFIELD  mergeFieldName </w:instrText>
... some tags
<w:t>«mergeFieldName»</w:t>

and "bad" looks like

<w:instrText>MERGEFIELD</w:instrText>
...
<w:instrText xml:space="preserve">  </w:instrText>
...
<w:instrText>anotherFieldN</w:instrText>
...
<w:instrText xml:space="preserve">ane </w:instrText>
```

Has anyone a suggestion - how this could be avoided?

Addition:
I'm creating this file in MS Word, not via code
but I deal with created file further, and my code can't handle "splitted" mail merge tags
so the real question contains of two parts
1. is this "splitting" is known problem in MS Word, or it's just my local issue
2. how to properly handle this "splitted tags"

Comment: Please provide more information. How do you create that docx? Sample code would be a good starting point for others to help you.

Comment: I'm just creating this docx from ms word

Comment: So you are using the office interop assemblies? Can you edit your question to provide sample code?